# call asmx to get facebook open graph Auth_Token, works locally, fails on server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, oauth

The code below works great locally.  However, when I publish to my host and run it it takes ~20 seconds and then responds with "Unable to connect to the remote server".

**edit: Got it, according to my host:** ' WebPermission to perform HTTP requests, e.g. to use external XML Web Services. (The access must be done using a proxy server servername.tld on port 1234)"

Javascript:

```
    function getAuthCode() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "backend.asmx/getAuthCode",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //do whatever
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert('getAuthCode ERROR: ' + error);
            }
        });
    };
```

ASMX:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function getAuthCode() As String
    Dim appID As String = "<my appid>"
    Dim secretCode As String = "<my apps secret code>"
    Dim authURL As String = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + appID + "&client_secret=" + secretCode + "&grant_type=client_credentials"
    Try
        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(authURL)
        Return result
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Check if required port is open to access the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered my webhost requires a proxy for any HTTP requests.  Updated function below works perfectly!

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function getAuthCode() As String
    Dim appID As String = "<my appid>"
    Dim secretCode As String = "<my apps secret code>"
    Dim authURL As String = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + appID + "&client_secret=" + secretCode + "&grant_type=client_credentials"
    Try
        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim webProxy As New System.Net.WebProxy("<host proxy url", True)
        webClient.Proxy = webProxy
        Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(authURL)
        Return result
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```